# deploy web project from Eclipse using JRebel

Tags: java, eclipse, jrebel

I'm trying to deploy a multi-module Maven project from Eclipse to a local Tomcat using JRebel. The project has the following structure:

```
root [packaging: pom]
|
|--- domain [packaging: jar
|
|--- manager [packaging: jar]
|
|--- web [packaging: war]
```

I've created `src/main/resources/rebel.xml` in each of the 3 child modules. I can deploy the web project to Tomcat (without using JRebel) from within Eclipse without any problems.

However, if I [change the deployment to use JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/reference-manual/server.html#server-4.2), I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance 
of class com.web.listeners.WebAppListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.model.Role
....
....
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.model.Role
```

`Role` is a persistent (JPA/Hibernate) class from the domain project and it appears to be the reference to it in `WebAppListener` that is triggering the error:

```
public class WebAppListener implements ServletContextListener, HttpSessionListener, 
        HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    private RoleManager roleManager;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        BeanFactory beanFactory = WebApplicationContextUtils.
                    getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext());
        this.roleManager = beanFactory.getBean(RoleManager.class);

        saveIfAbsent("USER", "Normal User");
    }

    private void saveIfAbsent(String roleName, String roleDescription) {

        if (roleManager.getRole(roleName) == null) {
            Role role = new Role();
            role.setName(roleName);
            role.setDescription(roleDescription);
            roleManager.saveRole(role);
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the `domain` classes are not loaded when this code is executed, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

What is the contents of your rebel files? They should look like

```
<classpath>
    <dir name="/absolute/path/to/projectname/target/classes"></dir>
</classpath>
```

If you're using maven, you can also take a look at a related topic: [Getting JRebel to work with 'mvn tomcat:run'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788414/getting-jrebel-to-work-with-mvn-tomcatrun)

Note: if rebel.xml also contains a reference to src/main/resources, it sometimes 
confuses some frameworks and you should try removing it from all rebel.xml files if errors occur. For example, the following conf is quite common, but may not always work:

```
<classpath>
    <dir name="/absolute/path/to/projectname/target/classes"></dir>
    <dir name="/absolute/path/to/projectname/src/main/resources"></dir>
</classpath>
```

Comment: yes, that's what they look like. The other topic isn't relevant, because I want to run JRebel from inside the IDE

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing

```
<dir name="/absolute/path/to/projectname/src/main/resources"></dir>
```

from the rebel.xml file in the domain project as described [here](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/forum/topic.php?id=1390)