# Run dynamic web project with maven in debug mode

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I built a dynamic web project with tomcat7 server on maven. To test the project I run `mvn tomcat7:run` every time anything is changed. This seems to time consuming.
Is there any way to run this in debug mode so I don't have to run project every time I change something in files? `mvn --debug` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have a look at [Remote debugging of Tomcat using Eclipse](http://davidsblog.eu/remote-debugging-of-tomcat-using-eclipse/). Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/).

See [the answer to this question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788414/getting-jrebel-to-work-with-mvn-tomcatrun) for configuring maven with JRebel.

Answer (score 0):

use mvnDebug for debugging/breakpoints.

Otherwise if any class change yup you have to restart (in order to recompile)